# Handling exceptions in a method

Tags: python, exception, methods

I'm writing a function that prompts the user for a value of 'r' which is to be used in calculating the distance between vectors (r=1: Manhattan Distance, r=2: Euclidean Distance, r=3: Minkowski Distance).

```
# This method prompts the user for the value to be used in distance calculations
# 1=Manhattan, 2=Euclidean, 3>=Minkowski
# I have limited the input to 1-9 for simplicity
def get_dist_scale(enteredVal):
    while True:
        try:
            enteredInt = int(enteredVal)
            assert (enteredInt <= int(9)), "Value greater than 9"
            assert (enteredInt >= int(1)), "Value less than 1"
            return enteredInt          
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input, try again\n")
            enteredVal = input("Enter distance parameter: \n1: for Manhattan\n2: for Euclidean\n>=3: for Minkowski\n")
            get_dist_scale(enteredVal)
        except AssertionError:
            print("Value outside 1-9.\n")
            enteredVal = input("Enter distance parameter: \n1: for Manhattan\n2: for Euclidean\n>=3: for Minkowski\n")
            get_dist_scale(enteredVal)
```

Then in the main program I call:

```
enteredVal = input("Enter distance parameter: \n1: for Manhattan\n2: for Euclidean\n>=3: for Minkowski\n")
distanceType = get_dist_scale(enteredVal)
```

I run into problems after the user has entered invalid input, then enters valid input. The valid input must be entered twice before it is accepted.
I'm sure I'm making a simple error, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Can anyone please suggest how to get it to take valid input after the user has entered invalid input?

Comment: Don't use assertions just to catch them in try-except. Also, your `try-except` blocks should  wrap the smallest code possible that can raise the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

```
return get_dist_scale(enteredVal)
```

in the exceptions.

But - validating an input in a recursion is not a good practice (security breach).
Too many attempts and you get a stack overflow error. my recommendation, switch to while loop.